# Sketch the phase portrait

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics

I'm asked to sketch the phase portrait for the potential given below. Also below is my attempt of sketching the phase portrait. I appreciate that my sketch is not fantastic but is it correct?

[phase portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLMbT.png)

Comment: All is fine, with two exceptions: orbits don't have corners and the tangents to the homoclinic at the equilibrium are also tangent to other orbits. Better also to add an orbit for an energy above the local maxima.